# change text shadow style on canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fabricjs

i am using fabric to change the text shadow for text object on canvas ,

```
  textShadow: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.3) 5px 5px 5px'
```

this works in above code ,, but when i try to set it to another color-shadow on click of another button it is not working .

```
$("#txt_strength").change(function () {
    console.log('strength called');

    var obj = canvas.getActiveObject();

    if (!obj) return;

    obj.set('textShadow ', 'green 1px 15px 4px');
    canvas.renderAll();

});
```

Please suggest ,

Answer (score 2):

You have a whitespace after 'textShadow '. Change it to `obj.set('textShadow', 'green 1px 15px 4px');` and it should work.
http://jsfiddle.net/Kienz/gvn3X/

Comment: is there any way to specificaly only change shadow color ? or size ? actually i want to write these two changes on different butons

Comment: Actual no. But i opened new issue on github for this: https://github.com/kangax/fabric.js/issues/819.

Comment: Now you can. fabric.Text.textShadow was removed - instead use fabric.Text.shadow (type = fabric.Shadow). After you initialize shadow object you can manipulate shadow values separately: text.shadow.color = value;

Answer (score 0):

You can use now:

```
obj.set({shadow: 'rgba(0,0,0, 0.3) 2px 2px 2px'});
```

full codes:

```
$("#txt_strength").change(function () {
    console.log('strength called');

    var obj = canvas.getActiveObject();

    if (!obj) return;

    obj.set({shadow: 'rgba(0,0,0, 0.3) 2px 2px 2px'});
    canvas.renderAll();

});
```

Comment: your code is working for me but How can I apply dynamic colour to the shadow. for example, In JS code I am storing the rgba code in one variable and I want to use that variable in your syntax instead of the static colour. how can I do that? I tried below but didn't work:
obj.set({shadow: '2px 2px 2px' + convertedColor}); where 'convertedColor' is a variable in which I am string the rgba code.